# Is the Source Code of Android TV's GBoard Available

Tags: android, keyboard, android-tv, gboard

I tried looking through google's repositories, but I couldn't find the source code for android TV's version of gboard. Is the source available anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

No, Gboard is a closed-source product.

Like many "Google"-branded apps (as opposed to built into the Android system), it is not developed as part of the Android Open Source Project, so the source is not publicly available.

The AOSP keyboard can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/refs/heads/master), but that is not Gboard (I'm also not sure if it works on Android TV).